# Is the set of functions $f(q)=0$ a ring with identity?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $S$ be the set of functions $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(q)=0$ for any $q \in \mathbb{Q}$.

Is $S$ a ring with identity? I believe it is trivial to prove that addition and multiplication are associative/commutative, but I am not sure how to show if it has either additive or multiplicative identities.

Comment: To be precise, you should specify the multiplication and addition operations you are considering (generally there are many ways to impose a ring structure on a set).

Comment: Functions from what to what?  $\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$?

Answer (score 1):

Define addition and multiplication in the obvious way. The zero of the ring is just the zero map, $0_S:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$:
$$
0_S(x)=0.
$$
The ring has one $1_S:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$:
$$
1_S(x)=\begin{cases}0&\text{if }x\in\mathbb{Q},\\ 1&\text{otherwise}. \end{cases}
$$

Comment: "Obvious" means "pointwise"? Easy to say so, and avoid spending time disambiguating... :)

Answer (score 1):

Just to clarify: for a set $X$ expressible as a disjoint union of sets $Y$ and $Z$, the collection $\mathbb C(X)$ of all $\mathbb C$-valued functions on $X$, with pointwise multiplication and addition, is a ring... and is a direct sum of the corresponding rings of functions on $Y$ and $Z$. In particular, the collection of all functions on $X$ vanishing on $Y$ is exactly $\mathbb C(Z)$.

In your example, the specifics are just noise: take $X=\mathbb R$, $Y=\mathbb Q$, and $Z=X-Y$.